# Dapper WHERE IN statement with ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, ienumerable, dapper, where-in

I am using Dapper on ODBC provider, which as known does not support named parameters. For most of my queries I used pseudo named parameters: `?name?`. However, when I try to

```
 string query = $"select * from \"{TableName}\" where ID in ?Ids?";
 return connection.Query<CdfGroupByCdfUserRecord>(query, new {Ids = ids}).ToArray();
```

I see that Dapper generates query

```
select * from "MY_TABLE" where ID in (?Ids1,?Ids2,?Ids3,?Ids4,?Ids5)?
```

What should I do to get it work?

Comment: A fix has been committed; I'm just checking for any 
regressions

Comment: Dapper 1.50.2 has been pushed to Nuget; let me know how you get on! (note: it might not appear yet - it hasn't been indexed yet, but [here it is](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/1.50.2))

Comment: Many thanks! It will take some time however, until it the update goes through our company procedures...

Comment: well, you cant say that I've contributed to those delays :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, I can confirm that it works. Thanks again, man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in dapper. I'll try to fix it for 1.50.2. I've logged it (for tracking purposes) [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/569)