# Dapper WHERE IN string statement with Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, where-in

I've seen [Dapper WHERE IN statement with ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527197/dapper-where-in-statement-with-odbc)

But I'm not sure Dapper supports WHERE IN ("String1", "String2") syntax for Postgres. Is this supported? I tried digging through the code but I really don't have the time at the moment. So far I've only seen examples of integers.

Example:

```
_connection.QueryAsync<Lookup>("select * from lookup where lower(discriminator) in @types", new { types = new[] {"Prefix", "Suffix"} });
```

Results in:
PostgresException {"42601: syntax error at or near \"$1\""}

Statement:

```
{select * from lookup where lower(discriminator) in $1}
```

Comment: Not sure about Postgres, but in TSql you have to put the parenthesis around the paramter like `in (@types)` because dapper just replaces it with a comma separated list of parameters names that it generates and sets to the values in the collection you pass to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I'm not wrong `IN` operator in Postgres won't support arrays as parameters. Instead of `IN` try `ANY` operator like below:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM lookup WHERE LOWER(discriminator) = ANY(@types)";

_connection.QueryAsync<Lookup>(query, new { types = new[] {"Prefix", "Suffix"} });
```

Comment: You sir, are a saint. My .NET / SQL Server background is showing. This works, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this, I had been fighting with the query for a while trying to figure out why valid sql wasn't working.

Comment: And also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730777/postgres-not-in-array for "NOT IN" equivalent.